# C# listbox Index vs Counts

Tags: c#, xml, file

i made a program that read a collection of xml from a directory, but my problem is when i writing the text file i made a test and i find this
i put 44 xml file inside listbox and the count is 44 but the index is 43. The last file the program can't wrote! :(

```
  private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {





        int a = 0;
        int total = Convert.ToInt16(ListCount.Text) ;

        while ( a < total)
        {

            string path = Convert.ToString(listBox1.SelectedItem);
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CAPTURE));
            FileStream read = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            CAPTURE cap = (CAPTURE)xs.Deserialize(read);
            textBox1.Text = cap.LOAN_CONTROL;
            textBox2.Text = cap.LOAN_NUMBER;
            textBox3.Text = cap.CLNT_NAME;
            textBox4.Text = cap.SOCSEC_NUM;
            textBox5.Text = cap.DOC_TYPE;
            textBox6.Text = cap.DOC_DATE;

            if (textBox1.TextLength == 8 && textBox2.TextLength == 10 && textBox4.TextLength == 9 && textBox5.TextLength == 7 && textBox6.TextLength == 8)
            {
                string loan = Convert.ToString(int.Parse(textBox1.Text));

                string file_name = Global.General.path1 + "\\success.txt";
                //string file_name = "C:\\Users\\Lesther\\Desktop\\test.txt";

                System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter;
                objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file_name, true);
                objWriter.Write(a + Environment.NewLine);
                objWriter.Write(DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine);
                objWriter.Write(textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine);
                objWriter.Write(textBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine);
                objWriter.Write(textBox3.Text + Environment.NewLine);
                objWriter.Write(textBox4.Text + Environment.NewLine);
                objWriter.Write(textBox5.Text + Environment.NewLine);
                objWriter.Write(textBox6.Text + Environment.NewLine);
                objWriter.Write("******************************************");
                objWriter.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                objWriter.Flush();
                objWriter.Close();


            }
            else
            {
                string file_name = Global.General.path1 + "\\fail.txt";
                //string file_name = "C:\\Users\\Lesther\\Desktop\\Fail.txt";

                System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter;
                objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file_name,true);

                if (textBox1.TextLength < 8)
                {
                    string loan_number = "    Error en el Numero de Prestamo";
                    objWriter.Write(textBox1.Text + loan_number + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                else
                {
                    objWriter.Write(textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                if (textBox2.TextLength < 10)
                {
                    string loan_control = "    Error en el Numero Control";
                    objWriter.Write(textBox2.Text + loan_control + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                else
                {
                    objWriter.Write(textBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine);
                    objWriter.Write(textBox3.Text + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                if (textBox4.TextLength < 9)
                {
                    string socsec_num = "    Error en el Seguro Social";
                    objWriter.Write(textBox4.Text + socsec_num + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                else
                {
                    objWriter.Write(textBox4.Text + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                if (textBox5.TextLength < 7)
                {
                    string doc_type = "    Error con el Doc Type";
                    objWriter.Write(textBox5.Text + doc_type + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                else
                {
                    objWriter.Write(textBox5.Text + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                if (textBox6.TextLength < 8)
                {
                    string doc_date = "    Error con el Doc Date";
                    objWriter.Write(textBox6.Text + doc_date + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                else
                {
                    objWriter.Write(textBox6.Text + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                objWriter.Write("******************************************");
                objWriter.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                objWriter.Flush();
                objWriter.Close();



            }


            if (a < total)
            {
                a++;

                listBox1.SelectedIndex++;

            }
            else
            {
                listBox1.Items.Clear();

                button1.Enabled = false;
                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox2.Clear();
                textBox3.Clear();
                textBox4.Clear();
                textBox5.Clear();
                textBox6.Clear();
                ListCount.Text = null;
                this.Refresh();
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you *please* condense your code snippet to the part relative to the problem?

Comment: a = is index, total is count
while ( a < total)

listBox1.SelectedIndex++;

Comment: "*the count is 44 but the index is 43*". Zero based index? item 0 to item 43, counted 44 items.

Comment: @har07 yes, but the last file is not reading

Comment: @har07 is not reading because the last file index is 43 and the count is 44, when it do the loop again throw an error cuz doesn't exist another index

Comment: your code has much distracting non-relevant parts regarding to this problem. I can't even see which part in the code you referred as *file index* and where is *the count*. Try to post small working codes that demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Listbox.SelectedIndex is most likely starting at 1.

Instead of moving the selectedIndex around, just use the items collection to get the specific item.

```
string path = Convert.ToString(listBox1.items[a]);
```